# ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

when I run the command is visual studio then it showing me this error -
ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Answer (score 5):

to enable script code runt this command

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine Unrestricted**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, make sure you are running it as Admin.

Enter this command from VS Terminal.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve using run cmd as administrator but make sure you have ionic already installed